# ModuleNotFoundError in Spyder with Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder

Hi I'm using Ubuntu and have created a conda environment to build a project. I'm using Python 2.7 and Pytorch plus some other libraries.

When I try to run my code in Spyder I receive a ModuleNotFoundError telling me that torch module hasn't been installed.

However, when I type conda list into a terminal I can clearly see torch is there. How can I configure this to work with Spyder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH may be pointing to the wrong python environment. Depending on which one is conflicting, you may have to do some exploring to find the culprit. My guess is that Spyder is not using your created conda environment where Pytorch is installed.

To change the path in Spyder, open the `Preferences` window. Within this window, select the `Python interpreter` item on the left. The path to the Python executable will be right there. I'm using a Mac, so the settings navigation may be different for you, but it's around there somewhere.